# change Emacs key map (from C-c s to C-\)

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to change the key maps in Emacs (for use with cscope). Cscope has bindings like

```
"C-c s s", "C-c s g", "C-c s G" ... etc
```

So I'm trying to change the map to `C-\ s, C-\ g, C-\ G ... etc`

I tried using

```
(define-key global-map "\C-\\-s"  'cscope-find-this-symbol)
```

It complains:

```
error: Key sequence C-\ - a starts with non-prefix key C-\
```

How do I correct this. I'm new to Emacs and Elisp. I tried using the define-prefix-command function as suggested in the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html). But it did not help may be I did not use it correctly. Can someone let me know of any resource that can help me make this change. An example snippet would also be of great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to change the definition of <kbd>C-\</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>.
However, <kbd>C-\</kbd> is already bound to a different command. (You can find out what a key is bound to with <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>.)

The basic explanation is: Your command would never be executed. That other command is already executed after the first key stroke. One way to solve this is to *undefine* the other key first. Then Emacs can turn it into a "[prefix key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Prefix-Keys.html)".

```
(define-key global-map "\C-\\" nil)
```

You also said "\C-\\-s", but you meant "\C-\\s". The "-" means "at the same time".

```
(define-key global-map "\C-\\s" 'cscope-find-this-symbol)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the global keymap, it makes sense to only adapt the local keymap in a C buffer. You can achieve this by adding a hook that gets called every time cscope mode is invoked.

Depending on whether you're using xscope.el (which is part of the cscope package) or cscope.el, you have to use slightly different code because they provide different hook variables.

#### xscope.el

```
(add-hook 'cscope-minor-mode-hooks
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key cscope:map "\C-\\s" 'cscope-find-this-symbol)
             (define-key cscope:map ....)))
```

#### cscope.el

```
(add-hook 'cscope-bind-keys-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (local-set-key  "\C-\\s"  'cscope-find-this-symbol)
             (local-sey-key ....)))
```

In either case, put the above lines into your .emacs file. The .... stand for further key bindings, replace them with more bindings to your liking.

After restarting Emacs, you should get <kbd>C-\</kbd> keybindings in addition to cscope's default key bindings.

Comment: This looked like a better solution (IMHO, because it is only changing the local mapping and does not effect other buffers, if I understand it correctly), But I do not have cscope-bind-keys-hook defined in xcscope.el.... may be I need to look more into the file and try to get this working. Does this method needcscope-bind-keys-hook to be defined in the xcscope.el file. I found that it is defined in cscope.el..... will try.... Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't know you were using xcscope.el. My answer was given with cscope.el in mind.

Comment: @yaami I adapted my answer to work for both xscope.el and cscope.el - I couldn't test it though.

Comment: FYI: I am using `xcscope.el`  and can confirm that the `xcsope.el` version works for me.